# Using "deprecated" HTML tags

Tags: html

For quite some time, I have been using "deprecated" HTML tags such as `b`, `i`, `u` in my HTML for projects where optimization is important. I would often find code like:

```
<div class="WrapperName">
  <div class="ItemElementName">
  </div>
</div>
```

A while back (some odd years) I noticed that Google used tags like the ones I mentioned in the search listings, obviously to optimize the output. So my example above could look like this:

```
<b>
  <u>
  </u>
</b>
```

I liked this and have been using it regularly ever since. I mainly use the tags in parts of the code that don't define the lay-out, but things like parts of a repeated container, because that's where the biggest win is to be made. Using CSS I unset the default properties of the elements to make them "clean" elements.

Even though in modern browsers you can use any tag name you like and it will work, I chose these ones because they work in older (IE) browsers so that I don't need to register them with the browser.

Is there any real objection against this way of working? The tags as they were are already deprecated (so don't add any specific value - like what I want) and they are short and work in all browsers..

Comment: What about the behavior in browsers that don't support CSS?

Comment: All browsers support CSS...

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz even Netscape Navigator 1.0?

Comment: @JanDvorak Who uses netscape?? [Browser stats](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) [Netscape is Dead](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_netscape.asp)

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz I never said "popular". But then again, you never know what may happen in the mobile sphere or the "geek toys" sphere or the "screen readers" sphere.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz Anyways, [NN1 is still possible to download](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/netscape-1-0-rc-1).

Comment: @JanDvorak, what about them? If a browser doesn't support CSS, using the 1 tag over the other isn't really going to help them. Also 99,99% of all sites will more or less be unusable without CSS. Discussing Netscape Navigator doesn't really seem constructive to me.

Comment: @Richard the point is that some browsers (say, screen readers) might respect formatting by tags but ignore CSS.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Now you are just being silly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements such as [`<b>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element), [`<i>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) an [`<u>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-u-element) are **not** deprecated, their meanings have just changed, so carry on using them.

(I have linked each one above to it's entry in the W3C HTML5 specification)

Comment: The meanings are irrelevant as regards to the question. Besides, the document you cite says: “This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.”

Comment: the links return 404 not found.

Comment: Argh! They've changed the structure since this morning! I have now fixed the links. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is irrelevant to the basic question whether some element is deprecated or not. You are effectively asking about the use of HTML tags as independent of their defined meaning, and even against their defined meaning, simply because the tags are short and you expect to override their default styling and impose your own. There are several arguments against such usage. They are not decisive against all kinds of use, but they make the use highly questionable on web pages:

Some elements have defined or actual functionality that you might be unable to override. For example, an `<input>` element takes user input and participates in tabbing order. This might not apply to the single-letter tags you have in your mind, but it’s worth noting as a general point about “free” use of tags.

Elements may have default rendering that you cannot (completely) override in (all) browsers. Especially older browsers may use rendering routines (e.g. for form fields) that are immune to CSS. This, too, might not apply to single-lette tags.

CSS is ultimately just presentational suggestions that may be ignored or overridden by a multitude of reasons and in a multitude of ways; see [CSS Caveats](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/css-caveats.html).

Search engines will handle tags their ways. For example, they may take `b` element contents as carrying more relative weight than other texts on the same page.

Maintenance of a page using tags that way gets complicated, especially if people not familiar with the idea will need to take it over.

It might be better to use undefined tags like `<c>`, `<d>`, `<e>` etc., even though you would have to “register” them with IE (it’s just one `document.createElement()` per tag name). But many of the counterarguments would still apply (and some browser might some day define `<c>` with some surprising meaning).

Answer (score -1):

`b`, `i`, and `u` are deprecated, and you should not make up your own tag names either since the specification does not allow that. Use the `strong` tag for things you want to emphasize and use `span` for the rest. `span` has the specific purpose of allowing you use it for applying whatever CSS you like to some text.

Comment: The downvote is for incorrectly stating that the b, u an i elements are deprecated.

Comment: The content of the comment is also irrelevant to the question.